# XQuery get data based on distinct values

Tags: xquery, flwor

My xml is like this:
full xml at [inputxml](http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/courses/reed.xml)

```
<course>
  <reg_num>10616</reg_num>
  <subj>BIOL</subj>
  <crse>361</crse>
  <sect>F</sect>
  <title>Genetics and MolecularBiology</title>
  <units>1.0</units>
  <instructor>Russell</instructor>
  <days>M-W-F</days>
  <time>
    <start_time>11:00AM</start_time>
    <end_time>11:50</end_time>
  </time>
  <place>
    <building>PSYCH</building>
    <room>105</room>
  </place>
</course>
```

I need to take distinct values for courses and return instructors that teach those courses.

This is my current code:

```
 let $x := doc("reed.xml")/root/course
 for $y in distinct-values($x/title)
 let    $z := $y/instructor
 return ( {data($y)} ,{data($z)})
```

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that you posted, the for loop is iterating over the sequence of distinct `title` string values.

You can't XPath into those strings.

Rather, you want to XPath into the `$x` courses and use the `$y` in each iteration to select those `course` elements that have the `title` equal to `$y`, then select it's `instructor`.

```
let $x := doc("reed.xml")/root/course
for $y in distinct-values($x/title)
let $z := $x[title = $y]/instructor
return ( {data($y)} ,{data($z)})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I am new to XQuery and still have not got the hang of it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In XQuery 3.1 you can do this with **group by**.

```
for $course := doc("reed.xml")/root/course
group by $title := $course/title
return ( <title>{$title}</title> , 
         <instructors>{$course/instructor}</instructors> )
```

Comment: Wouldn't that put similar values together in the output?
Instead of clubbing similar values and just provide one result for each title.
I know I can select the first element from the grouped list.
But I wanted to know if there is a way to just club all the same nodes into 1.

Comment: Please raise a new question that shows what output you want. I've no idea from this description whether my query produces the output you want, or whether you want the same output that the original poster wanted.